# How to connect to another computer(windows installed) with SSH?

Tags: command-line, windows, ssh

is there a chance of connecting to a computer that has windows 7 installed?

Will I be able to make changes even when the computer is off?

Comment: > Will I be able to make changes even when the computer is off?

Comment: Yes, there is a way but you need to install programs on the Windows computer, so we can't help you here. Try [su] instead. And no, if the computer is off you can't do anything to t because it is _off_. The only think you could do is switch it on via ake-on-lan or wake-on-wan.

Comment: Install Cygwin on Windows and with Cygwin, sshd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will I be able to make changes even when the computer is off? > There is no chance. To have ssh access to windows 7, you could install freeSSHd.